# How to convert array info into object array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert below array

```
 arr = ['CCORDER0000100','CCORDER0000103','CCORDER000040', 'CCORDER000041','CCORDER000042',]
```

to

```
Info = [
    {
        orderid: "CCORDER0000100",
        ORDERTYPE: 11
    },
    {
        orderid: "CCORDER0000103",
        ORDERTYPE: 11
    },
    {
        orderid: "CCORDER000040",
        ORDERTYPE: 11
    }
]
```

is there any good way to do it?

Comment: Check out the Array.map function: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this

```js
const arr = ['CCORDER0000100','CCORDER0000103','CCORDER000040', 'CCORDER000041','CCORDER000042',]

const Info = arr.map(x => ({orderid: x, ORDERTYPE: 11}))

console.log(Info)
```